# Add multiple images to author profile page

Tags: images, dashboard, profiles

I'm developing a directory style theme using multi-site and each new author needs to be able to upload 5-10 photos to be displayed in their profile page.

Is there any way of doing this? I don't mind if it's a plugin as this theme is for a client and not for general release.

Comment: did you get this working? I'm trying to do the same thing, but just with 2 photos: avatar and user pic.

Comment: I got a semi-workable plugin based on the User Photo plugin. It works ok but is quite cumbersome. I abaondoned the project in the end. I think the User Photo plugin allows for an avatar and user photo as standard though. I could be wrong, but I'm pretty sure it does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this for an author photo: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-photo/

And this one might give you multiple images for the author: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sem-author-image/

The final approach is to use a gallery plugin of some kind (NexGen Gallery Perhapse?) and create an album for each author, labeling it "John Doe". Then, call the gallery in the authors.php file and have it get the proper gallery.

Comment: I like the idea of having a gallery plugin, but how would the new author be able to upload images to their individual folders? I was hoping to make all this editable from within the site template as oppose to having to edit it via the dashboard

Answer (score 0):

Install NextGEN gallery, then install Capability Manager, then go to the Capabilities settings, select the role who's capabilities you want to edit, and allow them these capabilities

NextGEN Gallery Overview

NextGEN Manage Gallery

NextGEN Edi album

NextGEN Upload images

Now your users of the role you selected can upload their own images into galleries.